# posts_per_page no limit

Tags: query-posts

I want to return ALL posts with `query_posts`.  I tried setting `posts_per_page` to a really high number, but `query_posts` freaks out and doesn't return any posts.  What is the correct way to query posts without a limit?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'cat'            => '22,47,67',
    'orderby'        => 'name',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'     => 1,
    'depth'          => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => ?
    );
```

Comment: I've been Googling for awhile and searching the WP codex, but I just can't find a direct answer to this simple question.  I believe my question is worded clearly with example code, and what my attempt was (setting a high value for the argument).  I'm not a WP expert, so thats why I came here to ask the question.  Even providing answers to questions that seem trivial to you are helpful in growing these Stack Exchange communities.  I personally love seeing a Stack Overflow link in my search results, as opposed to a link to a crappy forum.

Comment: Also, thanks for the answer.  You should post it as an answer and not a comment, so I can accept it.

Comment: I've got your point and I do appreciate your effort in *writing* the question. I also agree that non-expert questions can prove themselves valuable in this community. On the other hand too many of such questions can discourage some experts from getting involved here. It's all about some kind of balance I guess. Anyway I'm a big up-voter so I'm looking forward to your next questions :) Have a great time here on WPSE.

Comment: PS: you also want to replace `type` for `post_type` (or remove this line altogether). I will edit both the Rutwick's answer and your question to prevent somebody from copy-pasting this little mistake.

Comment: @Maugly Thanks for the correction man... just focused on posts_per_page hence copied the typo! ;)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

-1 is your answer! Look for `posts_per_page` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters).

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'post',
'cat'            => '22,47,67',
'orderby'        => 'name',
'order'          => 'ASC',
'hide_empty'     => 1,
'depth'          => 1,
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
```

**Important caveat**: This can result in a very huge query that can bring the site down. Do this only if you are sure your database can handle it. Not in public themes or plugins.

Comment: Important caveat: This can result in a very huge query that can bring the site down. Do this only if you are **sure** your database can handle it. Not in public themes or plugins.

Comment: @toscho Adding your comment as an update to the answer.

Comment: you save my life!!

Comment: @DarlanDieterich Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 32):

Or alternatively you can pass [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)(which is what `query_posts` uses) the `nopaging` argument, which basically does the same thing..

```
$args = array(
    'nopaging' => true
    // Your other args, etc..
);
```

It will do exactly the same, but if you have to look back at it later and can't remember what you were doing, i personally feel it will be more clear to you, what it is you were intending with that parameter inside the args array.

As i mentioned however, they'll both actually achieve the same.

Can't hurt to have more than one approach, and it's always nice to share what you know, suffice to say that's the reason for my answer, despite you already having a sufficient one.. ;)

Answer (score 6):

From your child themes functions file:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpsites_no_limit_posts' );

function wpsites_no_limit_posts( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_home() ) {

$query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
$query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
$query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
$query->set( 'cat', '22,47,67' );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'name' );
$query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
$query->set( 'hide_empty', '1' );
$query->set( 'depth', '1' );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Ricardo's with some modification:

```
static $paged;
$post_ids = [];
do {
    $paged++;
    $defaults = [
        'fields' => 'ids', // Only return the ID field to make this query faster.
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'no_found_rows' => false, // We need pagination & the count for all posts found.
        'paged' => $paged,
        'update_post_term_cache' => false,
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    ];
    $query = new WP_Query($defaults);
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        foreach ($query->posts as $id) {
            $post_ids[] = $id;
        }
    }
} while ($query->max_num_pages > $paged);

return $post_ids;
```

This will dramatically increase the query time by only querying against the ID row and avoiding updating term and meta cache.

Comment: Nice! thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer for your issue is `'posts_per_page' => -1` because `-1` will return unlimited posts per page As the others users answer.

I just want to add an add-on to this Q/A,

If you want to get the number of posts per page from the reading setting on WordPress Administration Panel you have to call the `get_option()` function and pass `posts_per_page` as a string to it.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'cat'            => '22,47,67',
    'orderby'        => 'name',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'     => 1,
    'depth'          => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page')
    );
```

I hope this answer will help someone as it help me. Happy Coding Stackexchange Users

Comment: That's actually a nice addition!

Answer (score 1):

Or..

```
function getAll($arg, $posts_per_page = 50)
{
    $data = array();
    $page = 1;

    do{
        $arg['paged'] = $page;
        $arg['posts_per_page'] = $posts_per_page;

        $query = new WP_Query($arg);

        foreach ($query->posts as $post){
            $data[] = $post;
        }

        $page++;

    }while(count($query->posts) === $posts_per_page);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: You should add context to explain your code, your idea to solve the question.